# Formatter for Kotlin on IntelliJ

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I am developing an application using Kotlin and using IntelliJ IDEA as editor. But not sure how to set a pre commit hook to format the code automatically. Could you please guide me on this with some open source formatter and how to use it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You have two aspects:

1. Commit hooks are here:

[image]

[image]

Verifiy the that the check box are checked.

2. Koltin format:
   [image]